# Qualities Comparision of Rama VS Ravana, Krishna VS Kamsa?

Tags: krishna, ramayana, rama, ravana

I want, list and comparision; of qualities and characteristics between

Rama VS Ravana , Krishna VS Kamsa

(backed-referenced) from Scripture Verses

comparision among of those qualities

can we derive some **meaning** from

Differences between Qualities, Characteristics